# Remove list type in columns while preserving list structure

Tags: python, string, pandas, list, types

I have two columns that from the way my data was pulled are in lists. This may be a really easy question, I just haven't found the exactly correct way to create the result I'm looking for.

I need the "a" column to be a string without the [] and the "a" column to be integers separated by a column if that's possible.

I've tried this code:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(str)
```

to convert to a string: but it failed and outputs:

What I need the output to look like is:

```
a                                           b
hbhprecision.com         123,1234,12345,123456
thomsonreuters.com            1234,12345,123456
```

etc.

Please help and thank you very much in advance!

Comment: it would really help if you can provide your initial table

Comment: What do you mean by that you want to remove the [] on the `c_u` column? I don't see it in the examples. And did I get it right, that you want the ints to be in a separate column each? How many ints can there be at max?

Comment: Maybe `df['c_u'] = df['c_u'][0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the first part, removing the brackets [ ]

```
df['c_u'].apply(lambda x : x.strip("['").strip("']"))
```

for the second part (assuming you removed your brackets as well), splitting the values across columns:

```
df['tawgs.db_id'].str.split(',',  expand=True)
```

Comment: do you know of a method to do that if 'c_u' was not a type string? since strip can only be applied to strings? Is there another function that would work on just a list?

Comment: when you do df.dtypes what do you see for c_u

Comment: also - why don't you simply convert it to a string? df["c_u"]=df["c_u"].astype(str)

Comment: if i do that before converting c_u to a string I get an error that says series object not callable

Comment: I converted it to a string in the output image link, but then the columns output siingle quotes around the urls like 'abc.com' when i just want abc.com. but i guess i can just remove the single quotes now?

Comment: hmm that didn't remove the quotes, I tried this as well and it still didn't work: df['c_u'].apply(lambda x : x.strip("['").strip("']")) with double quote [ single quote and single quote ] double quote

Comment: check my improved answer - it should do the trick. x.strip("['") note the " and '

Comment: yup worked now, modified mine too from before, thank you very much!

Comment: anytime. just one comment: next time when you ask a question - always provide the table as text, it will really help us.